# Python class: passing in self.var as a method argument yields no assignment?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, self

I'm getting what seems to be curious behavior in python. I can't figure out if it's a quirk or that I've done something wrong. Why is passing in an object's self.var as an argument to one of its methods does not allow me to assign the self.var that has been initialized?

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.num1 = 0
        self.num2 = 0

    def selfexp(self, n, metric):
        result = n ** n
        metric = result
        print metric

a = Test()

a.selfexp(2, a.num1)
a.selfexp(5, a.num2)

print a.num1
print a.num2
```

Output:

```
4
3125
0 # expected 4
0 # expected 3125
```

Comment: I think his thinking is: `a.num1` is passed in as parameter `metric` to `selfexp`, and `metric` is later assigned a new value. Therefore, `a.num1` should also have this new value. It's a consistent mental model, but it's not how Python works.

Comment: `metric=result` is valid only inside the scope of `selfexp()`

Comment: @MartijnPieters he thinks that by passing a.num1 as the metric parameter, that a.num1 will update since he writes `metric = result` ...

Comment: I'm trying to pass in `self.num1` and `self.num2` into `selfexp()`, where it gets assigned the calculated result. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @d_rez90: Yes, it had clicked already, see my answer below. :-)

Comment: metric is only seen within selfexp() @Chrispy, any changes you make to it within that function will not be seen elsewhere

Comment: ah makes sense, thank you all very much for the education =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`metric` is just a local variable, and it is *not* a reference to the attribute. When you call a function or a method, python passes in the *referenced object*. That means the *value* referenced by `a.num1` or `a.num2` is passed in, not an attribute. In your example, `metric` is `0` in both cases because the result of the expressions `a.num1` and `a.num2` is both `0`.

If you wanted to tell a method what attribute to assign to, use [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) and pass in a *string*:

```
def selfexp(self, n, metric):
    result = n ** n
    setattr(self, metric, result)
    print getattr(self, metric)
```

and:

```
a.selfexp(2, 'num1')
```

I used the [`getattr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to read the same named attribute again as well.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `selfexp`, `metric` is just a reference to the same integer object as `a.num1`. Assigning a new value to `metric` inside the method just changes what the name `metric` points to; it does not change the object that `a.num1` points to.

Ned Batchelder has a nice [blog post](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) that explains the semantics of names and values in Python.